NSIS scit : You forgot ${Using:StrFunc} StrStr Error in macro STRFUNC_MAKEFUNC
I m getting !error: You forgot ${Using:StrFunc} StrStr Error in macro STRFUNC_MAKEFUNC on macroline 2 when i run nsis script.
Tried including below pligins and these .nsh files are present in include directory.
!include "LogicLib.nsh"
!include "FileFunc.nsh"
!include "StrFunc.nsh"`
Also documentation says to use below. i m not sure where?
${UsingStrFunc} StrStr # Supportable for Install Sections and Functions
${UsingStrFunc} UnStrStr # Supportable for Uninstall Sections and Functions
if i use this it gives
Invalid command: "${UsingStrFunc}"
    !macro CHECKPROCESSEXISTANCEMACRO un
    Function ${un}CheckProcessExistance 
    ;"Check File Running by User"
    ; Define the process name and the user to check
    StrCpy $0 "Sky.Suite.Dev11.exe"
    StrCpy $1 "pck"

    ; Check if the process is running by the specified user directly
    nsExec::ExecToStack 'tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq $0" /FI "USERNAME eq $1" /FO LIST'
    Pop $R0
    Pop $R1
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION  "$R1" /SD IDOK
    ${StrStr} $R3 $R1 "INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria."
    StrCmp $R3 "" Not_found found
    
    found:
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION  "$0 is running by $1. Please close it before starting the installation again." /SD IDOK
    Abort

    Not_found:
    FunctionEnd
    !macroend


!include "StrFunc.nsh"
${Using:StrFunc} StrStr

Section
${StrStr} $R3 $R1 "blah blah"
SectionEnd

